# How can I access UI of Locust in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, locust, load-generator

I deployed Online Boutique Demo Application(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo) on Google Cloud(GKE). I want to access to UI of load generator(locust) in order to change the load and visualize it on graph section. However, I cannot find which port it is running. I did "kubectl get all", and there is no service for load generator.

Comment: The loadGenerator of that app is not Locust per-se, it doesn't use the GUI. It's a python script that uses the locust python library to run some load (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo/blob/main/src/loadgenerator/locustfile.py) and the container run busybox to do some wget and also run the python script (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo/blob/main/kubernetes-manifests/loadgenerator.yaml)

Comment: I see. So in order to increase and decrease the load, should I update the python script?

Comment: Or you can try editing the USERS environment variable to see if that works https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo/blob/main/kubernetes-manifests/loadgenerator.yaml